# Failure to import javax.servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, import, javac

I know this is a common error, but bear with me. I've pursued the CLASSPATH problem and I don't *think* that is the issue.  I'm getting an error like this.

```
./src/process.java:2: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
```

I installed Tomcat and the Java SDK, and I know that Tomcat is supposed to supply the servlet API.  But what file is it exactly looking for?

I have the following settings:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_16
CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java;/usr/share/java/tomcat6

The base directory for tomcat: /usr/share/tomcat6
In this directory, /usr/share/tomcat6/lib is simply a symlink to /usr/share/java/tomcat6

tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api-6.0.18.jar is in /usr/share/java/tomcat6, is there anything else I need to be telling javac about so it will use this library?  Is there another library that I need?

For background, I'm trying to get a hello world servlet running.  The code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class process extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");

}
}
```

When I compile this with javac I get the following errors (amongst others of which this is the root cause):

```
./src/process.java:2: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
./src/process.java:3: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
```

I tried specifying the classpath on the command line as well with the -cp option, but I ended up with the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your classpath to point **specifically** to your JAR:

```
CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/tomcat/tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api-6.0.18.jar
```

When you specify a folder in classpath, it's only used to locate all **classes** within that folder. JARs by themselves are libraries (packaged folders, if you will) of classes and thus have to be listed individually. So, for example, you could do something like:

```
CLASSPATH=/some/location/myjar1.jar:/other/location/myjar2.jar:/some/classes/folder
```

in which case all classes from `myjar1.jar`, `myjar2,jar` and `/some/classes/folder` directory will be available to you. If you had `myjar3.jar` in `/some/classes/folder`, the above declaration would **NOT** add it to classpath.

**Update** As [McDowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell) pointed out, Java 6 allows [wildcards](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) in classpath that would pick up all jars in the specified folder. Wildcards work for **JARs** only, classes are **not** picked up unless the folder is specified again with no wildcard. Wildcards are also not recursive. So:

```
CLASSPATH=/loc1/*:/loc1:/loc2/*
```

would make all jars and all classes within `/loc1` folder and all jars (but not classes) within `/loc2` folder available. Deeper nested jars (`/loc1/nested/some.jar`) would not be picked up.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that Java 6 introduced wildcards for picking up jars from a directory. Documentation here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#searching

Comment: It was the CLASSPATH then! :)  Thanks for clarifying that.  I suppose I wrongfully assumed that CLASSPATH is like LD_LIBRARY_PATH and what not.

Answer (score 0):

You write something in console or *.bat-file.

> SET CLASSPATH=C:\java\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\lib\servlet-api.jar